# Android ConcurrentModification onDraw()

Tags: android, concurrency, android-canvas, concurrentmodification

I'm having an issue with an android application.

I have a thread that constantly iterators over a list or shapes, updates their positions, and sometimes removes an item from the list.  At the end of the thread's while loop it calls postInvalidate() to prompt a repaint.

Here is the code where modification to the ArrayList happens.

```
Iterator<Shape> iterator = this.myList.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
     Shape nextShape = iterator.next();
     nextShape.move();
     if(condition) {
         iterator.remove()
     }
}
```

The onDraw method uses a for each loop to draw each of those items.  I am getting concurrent modification in the onDraw method despite only modifying the list through the iterator.  I've tried CopyOnWriteArrayList and Collections.synchronized with the same results.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of ways to solve this.  One would be to use a synchronized block in the thread and in onDraw, but that would prevent the 2nd thread from running at the same time as the UI thread.

I think the best way is for you to use two collections.  Your code should look like this

```
onDraw(){
    synchronized(myList){
        //Do your draw code.  Get the iterator inside this block
    }
}

threadFunction(){
    List threadList;
    while(1){
        //Update threadList, which holds all the objects
        synchronized(myList){
            myList = threadList.copy();  //Do a deep copy, don't just copy over the reference
        }
        postInvalidate();
    }
}
```

This will make your draw function operate on a copy of the list made at the end of an iteration.  If you're working on a deep copy, you won't get any synchronization problems as the thread isn't altering the same list.  The synchronized blocks will stop the thread from overwriting the draw function's copy during a draw.  The only remaining issue is that the overwrite of the list in the thread will hang until a draw is done, but since updating it more frequently than that won't show on screen anyway, my guess is that's acceptable.